# Searching for strange characters ао in MySQL

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

This particular string ао is shown as M-PM-0M-PM-> when I view it via the command `cat -v myfile.txt` in linux. It's apparently not the same as letter a and letter o (ao) from my typical keyboard input. I'm not sure how can I perform an mysql string search for terms that contain these two strange characters  ао. When I tried `where columnA like '%ао%'` via mysql, I am not getting any match even if there is a record containing this strange ао.

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful

Comment: You must apply correct collation to the LIKE operands.

Comment: Do you have a Cyrillic keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to any of these?

```
E1B795     7637=x1DD5  []  NSM  COMBINING LATIN SMALL LETTER AO
EA9CB4    42804=xA734  [Ꜵ]    L  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER AO
EA9CB5    42805=xA735  [ꜵ]    L  LATIN SMALL LETTER AO
D0B0       1072=x0430  [а]    L  CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER A
D0BE       1086=x043E  [о]    L  CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER O
```

Please provide the hex for your text.  In Linux, use `od` or `hd` or `hexdump`.  In MySQL use `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...`

I don't happen to know if "ao" = "ꜵ".  Such happens in *some* collations for "ae" and "oe".

Your `ао` seems to be Cyrillic characters.  This is based on the letters in your Comment.  The letters in your Question are latin.  They look the same, but are not encoded the same.

Comment: Thank you. When I copypasted ао to https://codebeautify.org/string-hex-converter , I get 43043e. But when I do a reverse conversion there for 43043e, I don't get ао

Comment: That's a sloppy converter.  It left off leading zeros, thereby rendering it poorly.  It should have said `0430043e`.  I augmented my Answer.